# Pass a string from java script to python

Tags: javascript, python, html

I have a string on js that I know is there because it is printing on the console.

```
document.getElementById("export-string").addEventListener("mouseover", function(event) {
  const productos =hot.getPlugin("exportFile").exportAsString("csv");
  console.log(productos);
```

But I don't know how to pass it to my main app.py file. I tried:

```
@app.route('/nuevo_requerimiento', methods=['POST'])
def nuevo_requerimiento():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        #Preguntar por datos
        productos = json.loads(productos)
        print(productos, file=sys.stdout)
        ...
```

But it is not printing in the console so I dont know if it is working.
Can anyone tell me how to pass the data please? It is a cvs file stringified
I have no idea how to use ajax. I am very new to js

Comment: Using JavaScript, make an XMLHttpRequest to the Python file. Use FormData to embed the csv data in POST form data.